# Drawing on a UITableViewCell backgroundView using CoreGraphics

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, drawing, core-graphics

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell where I need to draw a custom backgroundView for the cell. Implementing drawRect:, I can draw the view fine, but it is behind the tableView and tableViewCells.

In order to use CG to draw my custom backgroundView, do I need to make a separate UIView subclass that I do the drawing in and set that as the cell's backgroundView?

Thanks!

EDIT: Screenshot

I want the blue to be drawn INSTEAD of the white. In place of the white. Or at least on top of it. [image]

I am drawing a shadow behind the cell using CA, and I would like to have this shadow behind my view I am drawing.

Comment: Show a screenshot so we can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the background of the contentView.

```
myCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor greenColor ]; //
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```